# How to validate a textfield for number only in Struts 2?

Tags: xml, validation, struts2

I am very new in Struts 2. I am having  three text-fields in my page, i put a validation for number only means (0-9) on that text-fields. In my validation.xml file code is like

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">

<validators>
    <field name="disSlab.minAmt">

        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>Required</message>
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="int">
                  <param name="min">0</param>
                  <param name="max">9</param>
                  <message>Data Not Valid</message>
        </field-validator>
     </field>

    <field name="disSlab.maxAmt">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring" short-circuit="true">
            <message>Required</message>
        </field-validator>

    </field>
    <field name="disSlab.schemeValue">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring" short-circuit="true">
            <message>Required</message>
        </field-validator>

    </field>

</validators>
```

I know that `<field-validator type="int">` is not for Number Filed . but i need to prompt user when user type anything except 0 to 9..

Can you please help me abt what should i put in that Filed for validation so i can resolved my Problem.. Thanks in Adv.

Dhrumil Shah

**This is not solution this is my further Details of my Question**

See i have debug the source code for validation lib. it generates client side query code like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm_updateSlabDataFormId() {
      form = document.getElementById("updateSlabDataFormId");
      clearErrorMessages(form);
      clearErrorLabels(form);

      var errors = false;
      var continueValidation = true;
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: requiredstring
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "requiredstring on amt";
          if (continueValidation && field.value != null && (field.value == "" || field.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length == 0)) {
              addError(field, error);
              errors = true;

          }
      }
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: required
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "required on amt";
          if (field.value == "") {
              addError(field, error);
              errors = true;

          }
      }
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: conversion
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "Conversion needed";
      }
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: int
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "Data Not Valid";
          if (continueValidation && field.value != null) {
              if (parseInt(field.value) <
                  0 ||
                  parseInt(field.value) >
                  9) {
                  addError(field, error);
                  errors = true;

              }
          }
      }
</script>
```

See This code is auto generated. This code is gerenerated when I submit the page. but its not generated before the page submit.. this issue is for only `<field-validator type="conversion">`
Not for type=required.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue..

**Finally my need is 
I do not want to reload a page for Number validation or any other regex validation. this is working for required validation only.**

Comment: What exactly is you problem here? Isn't it working already?

Comment: @doctrey - I don't believe the int validator specifying a min and max value would work for a String object.

Comment: @nmc Yes you are right, but if I'm not wrong in default stack of interceptors validation is done after conversion so we're already validating the int.

Comment: @nmc Thanks for your response. Ya that int validation is not working at client side. it will give me error message from inteceptor.. but i used Struts-Jquery-Ajax plugin for Validating textfields. when i put int validation or regex validation or conversation validation type. the control first will not give me client side error but it will submit the form and then it gives me error message in my FieldError tag. i dont know why this is working for required Validation Type and not for any other type.  I think Struts 2 gives us basic validation like interger value required and etc...

Comment: See i have debug the source code for validation lib. it generates client side query code like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not solution this is my further Details of my Question**

See i have debug the source code for validation lib. it generates client side query code like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm_updateSlabDataFormId() {
      form = document.getElementById("updateSlabDataFormId");
      clearErrorMessages(form);
      clearErrorLabels(form);

      var errors = false;
      var continueValidation = true;
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: requiredstring
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "requiredstring on amt";
          if (continueValidation && field.value != null && (field.value == "" || field.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length == 0)) {
              addError(field, error);
              errors = true;

          }
      }
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: required
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "required on amt";
          if (field.value == "") {
              addError(field, error);
              errors = true;

          }
      }
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: conversion
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "Conversion needed";
      }
      // field name: disSlab.minAmt
      // validator name: int
      if (form.elements['disSlab.minAmt']) {
          field = form.elements['disSlab.minAmt'];
          var error = "Data Not Valid";
          if (continueValidation && field.value != null) {
              if (parseInt(field.value) <
                  0 ||
                  parseInt(field.value) >
                  9) {
                  addError(field, error);
                  errors = true;

              }
          }
      }
</script>
```

See This code is auto generated. This code is gerenerated when i submit the page. but its not generated before the page submit.. this issue is for only

> Not for type=required.

**Finally my need is 
I do not want to reload a page for Number validation or any other regex validation. this is working for required validation only.**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Finally i got my answer**

Let me explain who can i achieved the Solution

My need is to put a validation for a textfield to validate Number only inputs.

I think Struts2 provide us this basic validation but i cant find it.

So i put a regex validation on my field like

```
<field-validator type="regex" short-circuit="true">
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[^[0-9]+$]]></param>
         <message>Not Valid Number</message>
 </field-validator>
```

This works fine with Ajax-JQuery Validation.
i Forgot to put **CDATA** in my regex. but now this works fine.

Thanks for your support.

Dhrumil Shah

Comment: I think nmc answered the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [regular expression validator](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/regex-validator.html)  to match the String to numbers only.

Comment: Hey nmc. thanks for reply. but this is basic validation type. its not good to use regex all the time. But Still regex submit the page and gives me error message in FiledError not Showing me above the textfield when i click the submit button. You can understand my issue.

Comment: @Dhrumil Shah-- are you using this plugin http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/Validation ?

Comment: Ya i am using struts2-jquery-plugin-3.0.2 version.